# How to run minecraft in window?

Tags: games, minecraft

I am running minecraft in fullscreen on Ubuntu 23.04, when I turn off fullscreen it appears to switch to fullscreen window mode. How can I scale the window smaller and drag it around my desktop?

Comment: change the resolution inside minecraft. Or click and drag the edges of the window, same as any other program.

Comment: @Esther Changing resolution in menu only works for fullscreen. When not in fullscreen, it is "fullscreen windowed", so it is impossible to drag the edges as the mouse is captured inside the screen with no edges to grab onto.

Comment: you can press esc to enter the menu, and then you can drag the edges. Regardless how you do it, you can never drag edges while in a game

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found was to edit minecraft resolution from the launcher.

From there you can set it smaller than your monitor and it will run in a resizable window.